# Saving data from DDBB into AS class

Tags: database, apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript

i am trying to make a "game" in Flex similar to Shake&Fidget. I'm saving all the user data in a mysql database and I retrieve the data using ZendFramework (PHP).
I thought of saving all the user and character info I'm going to need into am AS class so I can use that data in every view.

The data recived from the database is correct. I was able to load it in my app labbels but everytime i changed views it had to ask it again, so i thought of making this classes in order to just ask once for the information.

I'll post here the files so it's all more clear.

ViewNavigatorAplication.mxml

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                        firstView="views.RotrHomeView"
                        persistNavigatorState="true">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.net.registerClassAlias;

        import valueObjects.Character;

        registerClassAlias("Character", valueObjects.Character);
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

The first View goes to the login screen, it works OK. So i'll go to the view that loads and "tries" to show the character data.

char_panel.mxml

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:usersservice1="services.usersservice1.*"
    title="Character Sheet" 
    viewActivate="char_panel_viewActivateHandler()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.binding.utils.*;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        import valueObjects.Character;

        //[Bindable]protected var character:Character = new Character();

        public function updateStats():void{
            var str:int = parseInt(getGlobalStatsResult.lastResult.globalSTR) + parseInt(getCharacterStatsResult.lastResult.str);
            var dex:int = parseInt(getGlobalStatsResult.lastResult.globalDEX) + parseInt(getCharacterStatsResult.lastResult.dex);
            var intel:int = parseInt(getGlobalStatsResult.lastResult.globalINT) + parseInt(getCharacterStatsResult.lastResult.intel);
            var cha:int = parseInt(getGlobalStatsResult.lastResult.globalCHA) + parseInt(getCharacterStatsResult.lastResult.cha);
            var sta:int = parseInt(getGlobalStatsResult.lastResult.global_VIT) + parseInt(getCharacterStatsResult.lastResult.vit);              
            data.modStats(str,intel,cha,sta,dex)
            data.showStats(lb_show_str,lb_show_dex,lb_show_int,lb_show_cha,lb_show_vit);
            //character.showStats(lb_show_str,lb_show_dex,lb_show_int,lb_show_cha,lb_show_vit);

        }

        public function char_panel_viewActivateHandler():void{
            if(!data){
                data = new Character();
            }
            getCharacterStatsResult.token = usersService1.getCharacterStats("user01");
            getGearListResult.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,onResult);
            getGearListResult.token = usersService1.getGearList();
        }
        public function onStatsResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
            if(getGlobalStatsResult.lastResult.globalSTR != null){
                updateStats();
            }
        }

        public function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
            if(getGearListResult.lastResult[0].itemName != null){
                getGlobalStatsResult.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onStatsResult);
                getGlobalStatsResult.token = usersService1.getGlobalStats("user01");

                currentState = "Character";

            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="Loading"/>
    <s:State name="Character"/>
</s:states>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getCharacterStatsResult"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="getGearListResult"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="getGlobalStatsResult"/>
    <usersservice1:UsersService1 id="usersService1"/>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label id="lb_show_str" includeIn="Character" x="119" y="46" text=""/>
<s:BusyIndicator includeIn="Loading" left="172" right="171" top="148" bottom="424"
                 horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="-138"/>
<s:Label id="lb_show_int" includeIn="Character" x="119" y="90"/>
<s:Label id="lb_show_cha" includeIn="Character" x="119" y="139"/>
<s:Label id="lb_show_vit" includeIn="Character" x="119" y="191"/>
<s:Label id="lb_show_dex" includeIn="Character" x="119" y="243"/>
```

As for the AS classes:

Character.as

```
package valueObjects{
import mx.data.ChangedItems;
import mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel;

import spark.components.Label;
import spark.skins.spark.StackedFormHeadingSkin;

[Bindable]
public class  Character
{
    private var _name:String;
    private var _stats:FinalStats;
    private var _gear:GearList;

    public function Character()
    {
        this._stats = new FinalStats();
        this._gear = new GearList();
    }
    public function modStats(str:int,intel:int,cha:int,sta:int,dex:int):void{
        this._stats.modStr(str);
        this._stats.modInt(intel);
        this._stats.modCha(cha);
        this._stats.modVit(sta);
        this._stats.modDex(dex);
    }
    public function getStats():Array{
        var aStats:Array;
        aStats["str"]=this._stats.getStr();
        aStats["int"]=this._stats.getInt();
        aStats["cha"]=this._stats.getCha();
        aStats["sta"]=this._stats.getVit();
        aStats["dex"]=this._stats.getDex();
        return aStats;
    }
    public function setName(charName:String):void{
        this._name = charName;
    }
    public function getName():String{
        return this._name;
    }
    public function showStats(lbSTR:Label, lbDEX:Label, lbINT:Label, lbCHA:Label, lbVIT:Label):void{
        lbSTR.text = "" + this._stats.getStr();
        lbDEX.text = "" + this._stats.getDex();
        lbINT.text = "" + this._stats.getInt();
        lbCHA.text = "" + this._stats.getCha();
        lbVIT.text = "" + this._stats.getVit();
    }
}}
```

FinalStats.as

```
package valueObjects{

public class FinalStats
{
    private var str:int = 0;
    private var intel:int = 0;
    private var cha:int = 0;
    private var sta:int = 0;
    private var dex:int = 0;
    public function FinalStats()
    {
    }

    public function getStr():int{
        return this.str;
    }
    public function modStr(x:int):void{
        this.str+=x;
    }
    public function getDex():int{
        return this.dex;
    }
    public function modDex(x:int):void{
        this.dex+=x;
    }
    public function getInt():int{
        return this.intel;
    }
    public function modInt(x:int):void{
        this.intel+=x;
    }
    public function getCha():int{
        return this.cha;
    }
    public function modCha(x:int):void{
        this.cha+=x;
    }
    public function getVit():int{
        return this.sta;
    }
    public function modVit(x:int):void{
        this.sta+=x;
    }
}
```

}

And the last one GearList.as

```
package valueObjects{
import mx.data.ChangedItems;
import mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel;

import spark.components.Label;
import spark.skins.spark.StackedFormHeadingSkin;

public class GearList
{
    private var _headID:String;
    private var _shoulderID:String;
    private var _chestID:String;
    private var _bracersID:String;
    private var _glovesID:String;
    private var _pantsID:String;
    private var _bootsID:String;
    private var _main_handID:String;
    private var _off_handID:String;

    public function GearList()
    {
    }

    public function showStats(lbHead:Label, lbShoulder:Label, lbChest:Label, lbBracer:Label, lbGlove:Label, lbPants:Label, lbBoots:Label, lbMainHand:Label, lbOffHand:Label):void{
        lbHead.text = ""+this._headID;
        lbShoulder.text = ""+this._shoulderID;
        lbChest.text = ""+this._chestID;
        lbBracer.text = ""+this._bracersID;
        lbGlove.text = ""+this._glovesID;
        lbPants.text = ""+this._pantsID;
        lbBoots.text = ""+this._bootsID;
        lbMainHand.text = ""+this._main_handID;
        lbOffHand.text = ""+this._off_handID;
    }

    public function getOff_handID():String
    {
        return _off_handID;
    }

    public function setOff_handID(value:String):void
    {
        _off_handID = value;
    }

    public function getMain_handID():String
    {
        return _main_handID;
    }

    public function setMain_handID(value:String):void
    {
        _main_handID = value;
    }

    public function getBootsID():String
    {
        return _bootsID;
    }

    public function setBootsID(value:String):void
    {
        _bootsID = value;
    }

    public function getPantsID():String
    {
        return _pantsID;
    }

    public function setPantsID(value:String):void
    {
        _pantsID = value;
    }

    public function getGlovesID():String
    {
        return _glovesID;
    }

    public function setGlovesID(value:String):void
    {
        _glovesID = value;
    }

    public function getBracersID():String
    {
        return _bracersID;
    }

    public function setBracersID(value:String):void
    {
        _bracersID = value;
    }

    public function getChestID():String
    {
        return _chestID;
    }

    public function setChestID(value:String):void
    {
        _chestID = value;
    }

    public function getShoulderID():String
    {
        return _shoulderID;
    }

    public function setShoulderID(value:String):void
    {
        _shoulderID = value;
    }

    public function getHeadID():String
    {
        return _headID;
    }

    public function setHeadID(value:String):void
    {
        _headID = value;
    }

}}
```

If you are still here you have all my respect :D
When i try it out, i get the following error. I've tried in char_panel.mxml using Character::modStats(...) instead of data.modStats i'll put the error log under this one.

Error log when using data.modStats(...)

TypeError: Error #1006: modStats is not a function.
    at views::char_panel/updateStats()[C:\Users\Zebrah\Rotr\Rotr\src\views\char_panel.mxml:23]
    at views::char_panel/onStatsResult()[C:\Users\Zebrah\Rotr\Rotr\src\views\char_panel.mxml:39]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.rpc::CallResponder/result()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\CallResponder.as:122]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncToken/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::applyResult()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncToken.as:239]
    at mx.rpc.events::ResultEvent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::callTokenResponders()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\events\ResultEvent.as:207]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractOperation.as:244]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:318]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:56]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:84]
    at NetConnectionMessageResponder/resultHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\NetConnectionChannel.as:552]
    at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/result()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\MessageResponder.as:235]

Error Log using Character::modStats(...)

Error: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert valueObjects::Character$ to Namespace.
    at views::char_panel/updateStats()[C:\Users\Zebrah\Rotr\Rotr\src\views\char_panel.mxml:23]
    at views::char_panel/onStatsResult()[C:\Users\Zebrah\Rotr\Rotr\src\views\char_panel.mxml:39]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.rpc::CallResponder/result()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\CallResponder.as:122]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncToken/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::applyResult()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncToken.as:239]
    at mx.rpc.events::ResultEvent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::callTokenResponders()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\events\ResultEvent.as:207]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractOperation/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchRpcEvent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractOperation.as:244]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::resultHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:318]
    at mx.rpc::Responder/result()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:56]
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/acknowledge()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:84]
    at NetConnectionMessageResponder/resultHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\NetConnectionChannel.as:552]
    at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/result()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\MessageResponder.as:235]

Thanks in advance to anyone that get so far in this help cry :D i'd apreciate any sugestions that you can make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so the reason it doesn't work with data is that event though you said

```
data = new Character();
```

data is still actually an object (that now looks like a character).  to make it work

```
var myChar:Character = Character(data); // cast it to a Character and it now knows the method
myChar.modStats()
```

the reason the other call didn't work is the way you called it:

```
Character::modStats(...)
```

This say look for a method called modStats in the namespace Character.  Instead call this

```
character.modStats()
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You Sir are my personal Hero :D, i've just tried it and it shows the data.

I changed the constructor for the character in Character.AS like this:

```
public function Character(obj:Object)
    {
        this._stats = new FinalStats();
        this._gear = new GearList();
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, but as you mentioned in your answer:

```
var myChar:Character = Character(data);
```

I supose i'll have to use that data object to initialice myChar...am i right? Well, later when i have the time i'll try to add new views and buttons to go through views and see if the data is there :D

Comment: Here let me edit my answer to show you specifically and a cleaner way to do it